# Sphinx search s80hz returning owling

Tags: php, sphinx

Im new to sphinx so i was wondering if anyone had this problem or something similar and what you did to solve it. I have a list of addresses that im searching for and for some reason when i search for postcode s80hz it returns addresses with owling as the street. I thinking that sphinx changes it to owling somehow any ideas?

Comment: At a guess you have a crc collision. Is your index dict=crc? Try changing to dict=keywords.

Comment: sorry for late reply it is already is set to dict=keywords

Answer (score 0):

ok after much research and trail and error i fixed it what you need to do depending on your verison of sphinx is add dict=keywords like barryhunter said and/or also configure sphinx with this command ./configure --enable-id64 this gets rid of crc collision